# How can I add keypress events when I already have an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, addeventlistener, keypress

I'm building a web calculator.

It works fine when the user clicks the buttons, but I also want the user to press the keys. I'm not sure how to smoothly do this.

I've only included the event listener portion of my program since the rest of it is unnecessary to my question.

```
const a = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

// button press conditions
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // operators
        if (a[i].value === '+' ||
            a[i].value === '-' ||
            a[i].value === '×' ||
            a[i].value === '÷') {
                prsOpr(i);
        }

        // decimal button
        else if (a[i].value === '.') prsDeci(i);

        // equal button
        else if (a[i].value === '=') prsEql(i);

        // backspace button
        else if (a[i].value === '←') prsBksp();

        // clear button
        else if (a[i].value === 'Clear') prsClr();

        // any number button
        else logNum(i);
    });
};
```

Comment: I think you should use a button (e.g. the equal sign) and have a click listener on that, and then just use the keypressed event on the inputs.

Comment: Listen for the `keypress` event maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code uses an anonymous function as the callback to the click event and because it's anonymous, you can't reuse it for other events as well without duplicating it. So, separate your callback function out and give it a name. Then, just use a second `.addEventListener()` and point it (and the first one) to the same function:

Here's an example:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("click", foo);    // Set up a click event handler
input.addEventListener("keydown", foo);  // Set up a key down event handler

// Both event registrations point to this one function as their callback
// so, no matter whether you click or type in the field, this function 
// will run. But, all event handlers are passed a reference to the event
// that triggered them and you can use that event to discern which action
// actually took place.
function foo(evt){
  console.log("The " + evt.type + " event has been triggered.");
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: The question is far to broad to answer?!

Comment: @JonasW. Are you kidding me? It's actually pretty cut and dry.

Comment: I guess its still easier to attach two different event handlers in this case.

Comment: @JonasW. Why in the world would you attach different handlers that do the exact same thing?

Comment: Then could you show me a demo of the minus key doig the same as clicking the minus button?!

Comment: @JonasW. I would rework the function to take an argument that determines the operation to perform and that would solve the issue, but that doesn't alter how you get two events hooked up to a single callback.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, so all those if statements should be placed in a named, global function, and the event listeners should access that function?

Comment: @00Saad You should always avoid Globals as best you can and you can do that by wrapping all of your code in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression. But yes, you can then have different events on the same objects (or different ones if you want) use that same function as the callback.